# Concurrency control in shell

Tags: shell

I have two process P1 and P2. Second process P2 is running infinity. When first process is going to run then second process should going to waiting state until first is not completed.

Can you provide the easiest way to handle this situation.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But here's the options anyway:

```
 kill -s SIGSTOP $P2    #P2 - process id of P2
```

This will suspend the P2 which you can use when P1 is running and then do to continue:

```
 kill -s SIGCONT $P2
```

Or use `wait` in process P2:

```
wait $P1
```

This will wait until P1 gets over.